# Как создать и выдать роль с правами администратора человеку по его id

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно по команде `\autoadmin` создавать роль с правами администратора с названием `AutoRole` и выдавать его 2м людям по их id, это возможно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не нашёл там ответа на мой вопрос, один попробовал сделать, но это не совсем то, что мне надо

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def autoadmin(ctx):
    members_ids = ['id1', 'id2']
    permissions = discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
    admin_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name='AutoRole', permissions=permissions)
    for member_id in members_ids:
        member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=member_id)
        await member.add_roles(admin_role)
```

`cogs`

```
@commands.command()
async def autoadmin(self, ctx):
    members_ids = ['id1', 'id2']
    permissions = discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
    admin_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name='AutoRole', permissions=permissions)
    for member_id in members_ids:
        member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=member_id)
        await member.add_roles(admin_role)
```